# Wordpress permalink doesn't work

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

I have read a lot of documentation about this issues already, but it seem doesn't work with me.
After I choose the option 'Post name' in Permalink setting, it generate a file called '.htaccess' for me. I also enable apache2 module rewrite already.
The problem is when I click on any post or anything link, it show the message 'request URL ... was not found on this server.

Is there any step missing for this configuration?

Note: I install wordpress in Ubuntu 14.04
PHP 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.4
mysql  Ver 14.14

Comment: Have you restart after enabling the module ?

Answer (score 0):

First, Try to change **Permalink settings**, and then **create a new page/post** - links should be create correctly (with postname).

Also you can **inspect/refresh rules** with Rewrite Rules Inspector:
[Rewrite Rules Inspector](https://wordpress.org/plugins/rewrite-rules-inspector/)